# change mapped directory to not show full path

Tags: zerobrane

Is there a way to give a custom name or only show the **folder name** of a mapped directory in the ide, instead of the **fullPath + direcory** name?
They are completely out of line compared to each other with having names like e.g.

- `c:\documents and setting\user\blabla\anothernastyfolder\Mapped-Hello-World`
- `myHelloWorld-2`
- `myByeByeWorld-1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because this information is needed to facilitate file operations with that folder; all relative names are processed based on the project folder, so some of the operations will not work as expected. It may be possible to write a plugin that would keep that data elsewhere, and to shorten the name as the result, but somebody will have to do it.